# Is there a way to do a "run as" in a command line?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, permissions, windows-xp, runas

So, we are trying to push out the full .Net Framework 4 to all out client workstations within an Active Directory environment via the login batch file in the SYSVOL folder.  I added the following command:

```
\\server\documents\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64 /q /norestart
```

Works like a charm in terms of sielent initializing in the background when a user logs in.  However, I noticed it wasn't installing on some our lesser privelaged machines.  Sure enough, when running the intaller, it reports "Blocking Issues" and says "You do not have sufficient privileges to complete the operations for all user of the computer."  I'm open to other ideas, but this would seem the simplest if it is possible.

Comment: Not the sort of answer you're looking for but it seems to me that the easiest way to install this software would be directly via the software installation section of the machine GPO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start an instance of the command prompt as an Administrator:

```
runas /user:<localmachinename>\administrator cmd
```

Answer (score 6):

The command you are looking for is called `runas`.

More information with  `runas /help`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a scheduled task, set it to run as domain admin or any other account with sufficient privledges, then deply the task using group policy?